# Manage LMS channel (view/create/update/delete) from within the Salesforce setup menu

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps

**Is there any way to view created LMS channels from within the SF org, other than querying them from the setup menu? How do I delete the channel if I want to from the org ?**

I was able to to create a LMS channel and push it to the org (using VS Code and SFDX cli) and was able to verify that the channel exists in the org by querying it from the developer console.

below is the meta file I added to create the channel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <description>This is a sample Lightning Message Channel for the Lightning Web Components Superbadge.</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <description>This is the record Id that changed</description>
        <fieldName>recordId</fieldName>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <masterLabel>BoatMessageChannel</masterLabel>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

*PS: LMS channels is a very new topic and I did a lot of research elsewhere (including salesforce documentations and communities) but was not able to find what I was looking for. So even a link to the right documentation would help. All the articles I have came across so far only talk about creating and implementing LMS channel from VS code.*

Comment: is your file name BoatMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml?

Comment: I was able to delete the existing channel from VS Code using SFDX commands and then recreate it. But my question still stands, is there any way to manage the channel from within the salesforce org

Answer (score 1):

I was able to delete message channel using sfdx cli:

```
sfdx force:source:delete -p ./force-app/main/default/messageChannels/BoatMessageChannel.messageChannel-meta.xml
```

Make sure you use exact file name (case sensitive), you can check what you have in your org in workbench: https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDescribeAndList.php?type=LightningMessageChannel

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I don't see any direct sfdx command to deleting LMS from org but you can use destructive changeset to delete.

Comment: actually there is a sfdx command using which I was able to delete the LMS but I am more curious about is there any way I can manage LMS from within the Salesforce org. For now it looks like there is no way to view or manage the existing LMS inside the salesforce org from setup menu.

Comment: Yeah that's right currently there is no way to manage LMS inside the salesforce org